# $_POST checkbox array only returns single value

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

The foreach loop at the end with $_POST['clients'] only returns one value. Whats wrong?

```
 <?php $clients_to_display = Client::find_all(); ?>
            <p><?php foreach ($clients_to_display as $key) {
                echo $key->name; ?>:<input type='checkbox' name='clients[]' value=<?php $key->name; ?></><br/>
            <?php } ?></p>

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $job->name = $_POST["job_name"];
        $job->description = $_POST["job_description"];
        $job->type = $_POST["job_type"];
        $job->age = $_POST["job_age"];

    foreach ($_POST['clients'] as $key) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Comment: And if `print_r($_POST['clients'])`?

Comment: And btw - what is this `</>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does nothing:

```
<?php $key->name; ?>
```

I think you want:

```
<?php echo($key->name); ?>
```

Also, it has to be enclosed in quotes:

```
value="<?php echo($key->name); ?>"
```

Also the markup is invalid.  So, the full line should be:

```
echo($key->name); ?>:<input type="checkbox" name="clients[]" value="<?php echo($key->name); ?>" /><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton sg- it works. Why does the value part have to be enclosed in quotes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad to help.  All HTML attributes have to be enclosed in quotes for it to be valid markup.